# InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and not an instance of PinView; and no url property; and no path property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an app that uses the search box feature in the Google Maps/Places APIs to look up food banks near their local city or address.

The client-side looks fine in testing, but under the hood I keep getting the following error message in the console: "*InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and not an instance of PinView; and no url property; and no path property*". It doesn't seem to be affecting the searches being entered/returned and returns everything that fits the search query. I'm not sure what needs to be done for the error to go away. Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Here is my JS code:

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 32.714286, lng: -117.155577},
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 12,
        maptypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    let input = document.getElementById('pac-input'); 
    let searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    let markers = [];

    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      let places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }

        let icon = {
          url: places.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });

      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid: `url: places.icon,`.  `places` is an Array and doesn't have a `.icon` property.  That means `url` is `undefined`, giving the error: `InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and not an instance of PinView; and no url property; and no path property`.

Use `url: place.icon,` instead (the `forEach` assigns each element of the array to the `place` variable in its callback function).

Note (from comments): If you want the default red marker, don't use the icons from the place response (remove the line `icon: icon`, from the `marker` constructor, and the definition of the `icon` object)

```
places.forEach(function(place) {
  if (!place.geometry) {
    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }

  let icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  }));

  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1kcow9mg/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {

  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 32.714286,
      lng: -117.155577
    },
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 12,
    maptypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  let input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  let searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  let markers = [];

  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    let places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      let icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pac-container">
  <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" value="starbuck near New York city">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```